# when does the command line option -Dgrails.env = customEnv take effect

Tags: grails

*I want to know when the **Environment** is set to the option I passed as:*

```
-Dgrails.env = customEnv
```

***update***: I am running

```
grails clean  -Dgrails.env = customEnv
```

in short when does `Environment.current.name` get set to `customEnv`?

Which **file** to look?

Comment: What command are you running? Are you using Maven to build your project?

Comment: check startGrails script

Comment: What are you looking for? Are you not getting value `Environment.current.name` set to `customEnv`?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal yes, when I log the value of `Environment.current.name` I get an empty Map ( [:] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `buildCconfig` add:

```
import grails.util.Environment;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `clean`, it doesn't do anything. The two most common commands that `grails.env` is useful for is `run-app` and `war`.

For `run-app`, grails will run your application (using the embedded Tomcat) using the configurations that are specific to the environment you have specified.

For `war`, grails will compile a war with the data source and `Config.groovy` configurations that are specific to the environment you have specified.

This is especially helpful if you have separate environments that you would like to deploy to (e.g. - Dev and Prod).

Comment: It is because I am seeing message that says "environment set to `customeEnv`" when running `clean`. But my question is when does `Environment.current.name` get set to `customeEnv`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Setting grails.env when you clean your application has literally no effect. However, if you were to run `grails run-app -Dgrails.env=customEnv`, any code that references `Environment.current.name` would return "customEnv"

Comment: sorry if I am not clear. You are telling when `Environment.current.name` has effect but I want to know when `Environment.current.name` get set to `customeEnv`. If you know it just point me to the grails file that manipulates `Environment.current.name`

Comment: Why not find it yourself by doing a search on GitHub: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grails.env&type=Code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing the wrong syntax for firing command. System environment name needs to be passed first before command to execute and should not contain the spaces at either side:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=customEnv run-app
```

Comment: No, I can see the console output that says "Environment set to customEnv".

Comment: Okay, which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: grails version: 2.3.0